Classifier-Free-Guidance with Transformers

I'm working on music generation using transformers.
Using the decoder part for the audio tokens with text conditioning by the T5 encoder

In Classifier-Free-Guidance, the text conditioning randomly dropped with a probability of $p_{uncond}$. So when it's dropped, what should the cross-attention input be, or how is the transformer architecture modified?
Is it like when the text condition is not present the middle sub-block is skipped with an if statement?

https://github.com/facebookresearch/audiocraft/blob/adf0b04a4452f171970028fcf80f101dd5e26e19/audiocraft/modules/transformer.py#L569

Is it like when the text condition is not present the middle sub-block is skipped with an if statement?

Answer is Yes. See the link

Cross-attention reduces to self-attention

Hi @Sahil Goyal, and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! It may help the OP if you would add some more details to this answer. Thank you for posting, and we hope to see more of your posts here in the near future!

Can you provide references from previous works?

A recent reference that I remember is, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.00704 (see section 2.7).

Yes, Thanks! Also In below link (music gen using Transformers), there's a if statement as I asked in the question.
https://github.com/facebookresearch/audiocraft/blob/adf0b04a4452f171970028fcf80f101dd5e26e19/audiocraft/modules/transformer.py#L569
